# 3rd party authorization: Cognito User Pools vs Lambda Authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am studying aws and encountered the following use case:

> The development team at a company creates serverless solutions using
> AWS Lambda. Functions are invoked by clients via AWS API Gateway which
> anyone can access. The team lead would like to control access using a
> 3rd party authorization mechanism.

I think that `Cognito User Pools` should be used in this case, because it is clearly stated, that the system should use **3rd party** authorization mechanism.

But the course gives an answer `Lambda Authorizer`, which would require custom implementation of authorization, right?

So which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like **3rd party** means something, not related to AWS, in this case a custom solution involving Lambda Authorization is needed.